# Elixir + docker compose Connection with postgres refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, elixir

Hello I have a problem connecting to postgres with the elixir, I tried the following on docker-compose:

I used environment variables, but it wasn’t so I tried putting string in dev.exs, but even then it still rejects the connection.

I tested my postgres and it works normally and has the database created all right
log:

> postgres-db    | 2021-02-23 22:46:30.410 UTC [1] LOG:  database system
> is ready to accept connections

.env:

```
DB_NAME=spiritpay-dev
DB_USER=postgres
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PASS=12345
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
      restart: on-failure
      environment: 
        DB_USER: postgres
        DB_PASSWORD: 12345
        DB_NAME: spiritpay-dev
        DB_HOST: postgres-db
      build: .
      command: /bin/sh docker-entrypoint.sh
      ports: 
        - "4000:4000"
      depends_on: 
        - postgres-db 
      links:
        - postgres-db
  postgres-db:
      image: "postgres:12"
      restart: always
      container_name: "postgres-db"
      environment: 
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
        POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
        POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      ports: 
        - "5433:5433"
```

dev.exs:

```
use Mix.Config

# Configure your database
config :spiritpay, Spiritpay.Repo,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "12345",
  database: "spiritpay-dev",
  hostname: "postgres-db",
  port: 5433,
  show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true,
  pool_size: 10

# For development, we disable any cache and enable
# debugging and code reloading.
#
# The watchers configuration can be used to run external
# watchers to your application. For example, we use it
# with webpack to recompile .js and .css sources.
config :spiritpay, SpiritpayWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  code_reloader: true,
  check_origin: false,
  watchers: []

# ## SSL Support
#
# In order to use HTTPS in development, a self-signed
# certificate can be generated by running the following
# Mix task:
#
#     mix phx.gen.cert
#
# Note that this task requires Erlang/OTP 20 or later.
# Run `mix help phx.gen.cert` for more information.
#
# The `http:` config above can be replaced with:
#
#     https: [
#       port: 4001,
#       cipher_suite: :strong,
#       keyfile: "priv/cert/selfsigned_key.pem",
#       certfile: "priv/cert/selfsigned.pem"
#     ],
#
# If desired, both `http:` and `https:` keys can be
# configured to run both http and https servers on
# different ports.

# Do not include metadata nor timestamps in development logs
config :logger, :console, format: "[$level] $message\n"

# Set a higher stacktrace during development. Avoid configuring such
# in production as building large stacktraces may be expensive.
config :phoenix, :stacktrace_depth, 20

# Initialize plugs at runtime for faster development compilation
config :phoenix, :plug_init_mode, :runtime
```

logs:

> app_1          | 22:46:31.020 [error] GenServer #PID<0.368.0>
> terminating app_1          | ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp
> connect (postgres-db:5433): connection refused - :econnrefused app_1
> |     (db_connection 2.3.1) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100:
> DBConnection.Connection.connect/2 app_1          |     (connection
> 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5 app_1          |     (stdlib 3.14) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
> app_1          | Last message: nil app_1          | State:
> Postgrex.Protocol app_1          | ** (Mix) The database for
> Spiritpay.Repo couldn't be dropped: killed app_1          | [error]
> Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.330.0>) failed to connect: **
> (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (postgres-db:5433):
> connection refused - :econnrefused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point 1:**

Try replacing localhost by postgres-db in .env since the host of your database is that. You docker compose maps internal hosts to service names

Excerpt from the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) :

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
> container for a service joins the default network and is both
> reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
> them at a hostname identical to the container name.

**Point2:**

add [.env](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) to your app service:

```
services:
  app:
      restart: on-failure
      build: .
      command: /bin/sh docker-entrypoint.sh
      ports: 
        - "4000:4000"
      depends_on: 
        - postgres-db 
      links:
        - postgres-db
      env_file:
         - .env
```

In the above example you configuration seems vake you your environment variables defined in 3 places

- in .env which is not used
- in environment section of app service
- hardcoded in dev.exs
  the above will only create confusion and burden

in `dev.exs` load configuration from environment

**Point3**

the port number you use is wrong postgres operates on `5432`

**Point 4:**

You can test connection from host machine by listening to connections from everywhere `0.0.0.0` using:

```
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:5432:5432
```

then  you can test connection on localhost using netcat:
`nc -v localhost 5432`

Comment: i try this but no sucess, i put string on my hostname: "postgres-db", but dont work.

Comment: I don't even know why my database works normal, it has tables and etc.

Comment: really the problem was the door I put 5432 because I had another instance in 5432